# Play Dailymotion Link On VideoView Android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

Currently i am using [DailyMotion SDK For Android](https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-android) for playing dailymotion videos in my app. I was wondering that is their any posiblities that we can play the dailymotion video on VideoView?
I have tried many links which you can get from meta-tag from dailymotion website like:
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2nl9uz

https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2nl9uz

[dailymotion://video/x2nl9uz](http://dailymotion://video/x2nl9uz)

But none of this work on videoview as they are not a actual "video file". So is their any possibility that we can play videos of dailymotion without webview please do let me know.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: @johnykumar no .. apparently you can only use webview based dailymotion's sdk in your app. There is no other way (atleast what i have searched) to achieve this.

Comment: thanks for your reply,can i play both dailymotion and youtube view with direct link on dailymotion's sdk?

Comment: no ... you can only play dailymotion videos with dailymotion sdk .. you have to embed youtube sdk for playing youtube videos